# Distributing $3$ identical prizes to $10$ players

Tags: combinatorics

I have a statement that says:

> In a competition, $3$ prizes will be distributed among 10 players.
>
> How many ways can it be done if:
>
> I) All prizes are different
>
> II) All prizes are equal

I) The first prize can be dealt to $10$ players, the second to $9$ players and the third to $8$ players, so the answer is $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 = 720$ and, according to my text, is correct.

II) Here the prizes are indistinguishable, but here, I do not know what to do. I tried using the same logic of the first exercise, but that did not work, and I do not know why. I know I can use combinatorics, but that would be solving it without understanding it. Do not use any formula to explain it to me, please, just logic.

Comment: You pick $3$ people in the first one. Now the orden is irrelevant, so divide by the way of ordering them i.e., $3!$.

Comment: why divide "by the way of ordering them"?

Comment: @Phicar The answer to the first question is correct, provided each person can receive only one prize (otherwise, the answer would be $10^3$).  We need to match people with prizes.  Since the prizes are different, it matters which person receives which prize.

Comment: In the second question, what matters is which three people receive the prizes (again, assuming each person can receive only one prize).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes,i meant for the second one. Thanks.

Comment: The important thing is that three people will receive three prizes. But following the same logic, which I applied in the first problem, even though the three prizes are equal, the first prize will still have 10 people to be distributed, the second will have 9 and the third 8, then, that the prizes will be the same, Would you change the number of people to share? (I do not think so), how does it influence that they are the same? More than getting to the result, I want to know why logic does not apply, but, from this point of view?

Comment: If the prizes are the same, there is no first prize, second prize, or prizes, just prizes.  We need to choose three recipients for the prizes, which can be done in $\binom{10}{3}$ ways.

Comment: So is the same than 3 prizes to one player

Answer (score 1):

Let the first three players with the winner. Their possible rankings are

$$\{(1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)\}$$

However the order doesn't matter if the prizes are indistinguishable, hence those $6$ configurations are indistinguishable to us, hence we need to divide by $3!$.

$$\frac{720}{3!}=120.$$

Comment: if 6 configurations are indistinguishable, why divide instead of substract ?

Comment: because we are overcounting by $6$ times.

Answer (score 1):

Mattiu, to solve your question: 
In the first case, as you did $10*9*8$ what you are really doing is this: If you have just 4 people, say $A,B,C,D$ then your argument would say that we have $4*3*2$ this first $4$ let us choose $A,B,C,D$ then let's pick $A$ then let's pick $B$ out of the $3$ and then pick $C$ out of the $2,$ then the prices are given (in order) to
$A,B,C.$
Now, we can pick the same people in a different order, say first $B,$ then $A,$ and for last $C$ hence $B,A,C.$ the problem is that all of this possibilities are the same in the second problem, and hence you have $3!$ possibilities to pick the same people.
 So each solution that you have without order say $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ you can associate it with a function that takes care of the order, and so an ordered pick is a tuple $(\{a_1,a_2,a_3\},f)$ with $f$ a bijection from the set $\{1,2,3\}$ to the set $\{1,2,3\}$ and there are $3!$ of those and hence

$$Ordered = Unordered\times \hspace{1mm}Bijection$$ and so $4*3*2 = Unordered*\hspace{1mm}3!$ and hence $\frac{4*3*2}{3*2}=Unordered.$

Just for completion, the Ordered case is called a permutation and the unordered is called a Combination and can be computed using binomial numbers $n\choose k$ (way to choose $k$ elements out of $n$ elements without order).